# c# entity framework open and closing instance of dbcontext for every method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

1. Is is "bad" to have an newing up instantiation of dbcontext , if so what can i do different ?
2. static bad idea on this methods?

**web api**

```
public IEnumerable<GetUtilityPrograms_Result> GetUtilityPrograms(int vendorid, int officeid, string state,string zip)
    {
        var utilityPrograms = Business.AppLogic.GetUtilityPrograms(vendorid, officeid, state, zip);
        return utilityPrograms;
    }
```

**business logic**

```
    public static List<GetVerifiedChartDetail_Result> GetVerifiedChartDetailData(DateTime sDate, int vendorId, int officeId)
    {
        List<GetVerifiedChartDetail_Result> verifiedChart;
        int? v = (vendorId == 0 ? new int?() : vendorId);
        int? o = (officeId == 0 ? new int?() : officeId);
        using (CustomSparkPortalDataEntities ctx = new CustomSparkPortalDataEntities())
        {
            verifiedChart = ctx.GetVerifiedChartDetail(sDate, v, o).ToList();
        }
        return verifiedChart;
    }

    public static List<GetVerifiedAccountsChartSummary_Result> GetVerifiedAccountsChartData(DateTime sDate, int vendorId, int officeId)
    {
        List<GetVerifiedAccountsChartSummary_Result> verifiedChart;
        int? v = (vendorId == 0 ? new int?() : vendorId);
        int? o = (officeId == 0 ? new int?() : officeId);
        using (CustomSparkPortalDataEntities ctx = new CustomSparkPortalDataEntities())
        {
            verifiedChart = ctx.GetVerifiedAccountsChartSummary(sDate, v, o).ToList();
        }
        return verifiedChart;
    }
```

**Call to the DataEntitities**

```
   public CustomSparkPortalDataEntities()
        : base()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Using new context per logical operation is perfectly fine, even in web api. Create context, do what you need, dispose it (do not store it in a field if poasible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For Web API I highly recommend to use 1 **DbContext per HTTP request**. There is a million of discussions on stackoverflow how to approach it so I am not going to dive into details. The basic idea is to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Items` to share context between classes (using lazy initialization). Dispose the context on request end or in MVC filter `OnActionExecuted` once request is processed and context is not needed. [Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/05/18/how-to-manage-objectcontext-per-request-in-aspnet/) is where you can start (Change old ObjectContext to new DbContext). For later and as food for thought you might want to use IoC framework like Ninject, Autofac or Castle.Windsor to automate dependency injection and make your code more testable.
2. Never put DbContext in a static field. It's not thread-safe and you need to dispose it once you're done using it.

### Regarding context per method

It is acceptable but I really don't like it and there are reasons:

1. You manage it manually - for every method you have to copy-paste `using(var context = new MyContext()) { ... }` - it's a lot of code.
2. You may experience issues with managing entities as entities may come from different contexts. You would have to `context.Attach(entity)` before actually using it with different context from the original.

Comment: So if i removed static  , that using statement per call is ok  ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller the way you do it with initializing the context in each method and disposing it right away once you're done is acceptable. The problem here is 1. inconvenience, 2. you open new database connection every method call. If you have context per request you would gain some performance as you share 1 connection per several db calls.

Comment: While there is a ton of things on stackoverflow , is there an article that you like that keeps it simple etc.. ?

Comment: Point 2 is not true because almost always database connections are pooled and so is not opened and closed every time.

Comment: @Evk good point. It is pooled! but on the database level. But when you create context you still have to actually get the connection from the database which is more expensive than if you share the context and just have it per request.

Comment: It is pooled on client side, not on database level.

Comment: @JeremyMiller see my updated answer

Comment: @AndreiM    ObjectContext from 7 years ago  ?

Comment: Actually disposing context soon might be good for perfomance, especially if you perform some long operations during request (like file upload), because then connection is returned to the pool and is immediately available for other requests. Say you perform 5 minute upload, and new request comes in. That request will have to open second database connection, because first one is hold by upload request for no good reason. If you have returned it to the pool during upload - second request could have reused it and avoid cost of opening db connection.

Comment: @JeremyMiller sorry yeah it's an old post, but you can adapt it to a new DbContext class. Just change the type, it should work.

Comment: @Evk it is true only for parallel operations but for parallel operations you should use different DbContexts regardless as they are not thread-safe.

Comment: Well requests in web server (and we are talking about web api here) ARE parallel operations. And of course different contexts are used, since I propose to create new context for every logical operation, not one per request. So not sure what you mean with your last comment.

Comment: @Evk I see your point and I agree with you here. There are situations where you can definitely benefit from per logical operation context. Let's stop here. Thank you for this discussion, I think I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is place inside the class the database instance in this way

```
private readonly CustomSparkPortalDataEntities ctx = new CustomSparkPortalDataEntities();
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: If you initialize your context like that you should make your host class IDisposable and dispose the context. Otherwise it's a bad practice as you don't manage disposable resources properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from MSDN's doc

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx

> Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the context:
>
> - When working with long-running context consider the following:
>
>   - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause performance issues.
>   - Remember to dispose of the context when it is no longer required.
>   - If an exception causes the context to be in an unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate.
>   - The chances of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between the time when the data is queried and updated grows.
> - When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a context instance per form. This lets you use change-tracking functionality that context provides.